# 512 error UDF MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, triggers, user-defined-functions

I want to run a script from a trigger in MySQL using UDF. I have tested other simple script, and it works.

I am trying to use run a new one, but i have no result amd i get:

```
mysql> SELECT sys_exec('/var/lib/mysql/script_mac');
+---------------------------------------+
| sys_exec('/var/lib/mysql/script_mac') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                   512 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

When i use this for example in the trigger: echo -e "hello" >> /tmp/hello I get 512 exit code , when i remove ">> /tmp/hello", it works. I think the problem is in the ">>". So how to solve this ?

Regards

Comment: Investigate why that script is returning a 512 exit code...

Comment: how ? What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

The user changes on MySQL triggers.  It will create a new file with the trigger, which will have new permissions and owner.  If trigger is executed by different users you will need to allow global write to the file, to allow all users to write to it.